# How do I insert output from a PHP return into an HTML <div>? (I'm using WordPress)

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I created a quick Wordpress shortcode so my writers can easily style out a subtitle in the Visual editor of a post:

```
function subtitle( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<p class="subtitle">' . $content . '</p>';
}
```

I want to move this output to inside a specified  elsewhere in the document, example:

```
<div id="output_here_please"></div>

<?php the_content(); /* It is returned here wherever they place the shortcode */ ?>
```

What is the best way to do this? Is there a PHP or WordPress function to use, or should I create a javascript to replace innerHTML (I tried this but didn't know how to insert it AFTER the page loads).

Thanks

Comment: If you're not rendering `<div id="output_here_please">`, then client-side JavaScript. Depending on what is creating that element, though, you may be able to move your PHP code elsewhere (or trigger it with one of the WordPress hooks) so it so you can directly modify the `<div>`

Comment: You should use a custom field instead if you are planning on using this outside of the content.

Comment: custom fields with get_post_meta() worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is called subtitle like that, then they can insert it with:

```
<div id="output_here_please">
  <?php subtitle("value", "This is some sample content"); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way of doing it is to declare a global variable - say `$subtitle_content`, and use it to store temporarily the html fragment you wish to display *elsewhere*.

```
function subtitle( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $GLOBALS["subtitle_content"] = '<p class="subtitle">' . $content . '</p>';
    return "";
}

function the_content(){
    echo $GLOBALS["subtitle_content"];
    /* unset $GLOBALS["subtitle_content"]; */
}
```

You may want to undefine that variable once it becomes unnecessary, as written in the commented out code above.

[Documentation on `$GLOBAL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) for your information.

Note:

- you may want to use more specific names for your functions, to avoid name collisions with other functions (although PHP will abruptly tell you if this happens).
- don't use javascript for that, this is strictly server-side cuisine.